# JAX-RS Client: Spring security returns login page

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jersey, jax-rs

After implementing custom authentication using Spring security `AuthenticationProvider` and it works good but when I implemented JAX-RS client:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

final String URI = "http://localhost:8383/";

String username = "haikel";
String password = "blockchainGED2014!";

Form mapForm = new Form();
mapForm.param("username", username).param("password", password);


Invocation.Builder builder = client.target(URI)
        .path("login")
        .request();

Response response = builder.post(Entity.entity(mapForm, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));

System.out.println(response.getStatus());
System.out.println(response.getCookies());
```

it returns 200 and the `login.html` page in the body and without cookies I tested this call with cURL:

```
 curl -v -X POST 'http://localhost:8383/login' -d'username=haikel&password=blockchainGED2014!'
```

and it works too

I changed the form with `MultivaluedMap` and adding the params in builder

```
Invocation.Builder builder = client.target(URI)
                .queryParam("username", username)
                .queryParam("password", password)
                .path("login")
                .request();
```

but it shows the same result 200 no cookies and `login.html` in the body.

Some help please ! Thank you

Comment: What is the expected result? What goes wrong?

Comment: is that the response still return the login page and the response does not contain cookies

Comment: It seems that you have just described the actual result again. Should the expected result be something like: logged in successfully, etc?